# Linux find files where mtime and ctime are not equal

Tags: linux, shell, ctime

Can I do a `find` and list files where ctime and mtime are not equal?

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -ctime -5 MISSING_PART
```

MISSING_PART: something like `-mtime != -ctime`

Comment: Sorry - I don't know of any such option in "find".  I assume you know  [the difference between ctime and mtime](http://www.linux-faqs.info/general/difference-between-mtime-ctime-and-atime), and that the two are *usually* the same.  SUGGESTION: try writing a script using `stat | cut | diff`: http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat.  You can format the output so that ctime is in one column; mtime in another, then "diff" the two columns.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The two a typically only diffeent, if someone explicit set the mtime to something else than what is should be (typically a hacker)

Answer (score 6):

This can be obtained using `stat` command. The `stat` command is used to display file or file system status. The `-c` option is used to specify the format of the output of this command. The `%n` format is used to specify the file name. The `%Y` is used to specify the time of last modification since epoch and `%Z` specifies the time of last change since epoch.

The command `find . -exec stat -c %n#%Y#%Z {} \; | awk -F# '{if ($2 != $3) print $1}'` can be used to extract files whose change time and modification time are not equal.

The `-ctime n` and `-mtime n` options for `find` refer to last changed or modified time since `n` **hours ago**. This concept of range of time is not captured in this command.

Comment: It gives me a huge result including loads of cache files. But now I have something to work with. Thanks